# find match then include everything to the end of the line

Tags: ruby, regex

How would I match 'ber' to the end so it picks up 'ber/sunday/wednesday'

monday/october/sunday/wednesday

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`/ber.*/` for one-line string

`/ber.*?$/m` for multiline string, where `ber` can be not in the first line

Answer (score 3):

Something like `ber.*$`.

Answer (score 0):

Just use `ber.*`

Answer (score 0):

```
"monday/october/sunday/wednesday".match(/ber.*/)
```